# Optimizar un Procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

¿Cómo puedo optimizar? Ya que consulto 27 puntos de venta y es lento al ejecutar, local server groups.

```
USE [_Cliente_PDV0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_InfoProyeccion]    Script Date: 17/01/2019 2:15:43 p. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InfoSalidasEfectivo] 

         @Year NVARCHAR(4),
         @Month NVARCHAR(2)
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Efectivos](
    [codbodega] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Consecutivo] [char](20) NULL,
    [Fecha] [datetime] NULL,
    [observacion] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [nombre] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [nit] [char](30) NULL,
    [valor] [numeric](20,2) NULL ,
    [nombre1] [char](100) NULL,
    [apellido] [char](100) NULL,
    [apellido1] [char](100) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO #Efectivos  

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo, T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit, T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN APTDPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo 
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN BCOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)


INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  BELPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN BELPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN BELPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN BELPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  BQLLAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN BQLLAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN BQLLAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN BQLLAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)


INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  CALIPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN CALIPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN CALIPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN CALIPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
--WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  CALPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN CALPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN CALPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN CALPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  CARTPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN CARTPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN CARTPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN CARTPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN COPPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  DQUPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN DQUPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN DQUPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN DQUPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN ENVPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  ITAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN ITAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN ITAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN ITAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  L80PORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN L80PORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN L80PORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN L80PORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  LACASTELLANAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN LACASTELLANAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN LACASTELLANAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN LACASTELLANAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  LADORADAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN LADORADAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN LADORADAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN LADORADAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 


INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  MAYPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN MAYPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN MAYPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN MAYPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

  INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

  INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN MINPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

   INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  MONPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN MONPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN MONPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN MONPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 


   INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  NIQPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN NIQPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN NIQPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN NIQPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 


    INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  PALMPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN PALMPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN PALMPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN PALMPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

    INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  PDFPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN PDFPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN PDFPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN PDFPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

    INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month) 

    INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  RIOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN RIOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN RIOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN RIOPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

   INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  SABPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN SABPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN SABPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN SABPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

INSERT INTO #Efectivos

SELECT T1.codbodega, T1.consecutivo,T1.fecha, T1.observacion, T2.nombre, T1.nit,  T0.valor, T3.nombre1, T3.apellido, T3.apellido1
FROM  TULPORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtoefectivo AS T0 
                          INNER JOIN TULPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencefectivo T1 ON T0.codbodega=T1.codbodega
                          AND T0.entrada=T1.entrada AND T0.consecutivo=T1.consecutivo
                          INNER JOIN TULPORCIPOS.dbo.tblbodegas AS T2 ON T1.codbodega=T2.codbodega
                          INNER JOIN TULPORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios T3 ON T1.nit=T3.codigo
WHERE (YEAR(FECHA) = @Year) AND  (MONTH(FECHA) = @Month)

SELECT *
FROM #Efectivos




----exec   SP_InfoSalidasEfectivo '2019','01'
```

Comment: Los 27 puntos de venta entiendo que son las 27 tablas diferentes. Igual no estoy entendiendo bien lo que quieres, pero igual es un problema de diseño. ¿No sería mejor tener todo en una tabla con una columna que sea "PuntoDeVentaId" y otra tabla que sea "PuntosDeVenta"? Igual lo estoy viendo yo mal, pero no veo mucha lógica a tener tantas tablas diferentes con las mismas columnas.

Comment: Hola, tenia que crear un procedimiento que consultara información de 27 puntos de venta para luego hacer una macro en excel llamar el procedimiento con los dos parámetros  y generar el informe y suelta la información en una hoja de excel esta fue la única forma que medio pero se demora mucho consultando

Answer (score 0):

recomendable evitar el uso de funciones escalares sobre columnas dentro del **WHERE**.

Debes declarar 2 variables de tipo fecha para filtrar en el rango de un mes.

```
DECLARE 
    @Desde DATE = @Year+@Month+'01',
    @Hasta DATE = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@Year+@Month+'01'));--PRIMER DIA DEL MES SIGUIENTE
```

Luego usarlas así:

```
WHERE FECHA >= @Desde AND FECHA < @Hasta;
```